# "User ADMIN has no privileges on the schema." contact your app administrator, getting this error using oracle apex 18.2

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle18c, oracle-apex-18.2

I installed **oracle apex 18.2 with oracle 18c** successfully. then I created new workspace and schema, but when I tried to open it gives the error "**User ADMIN has no privileges on the schema.**"  I can't create DB objects neither create any applications. Also can't install existing sample applications.
Can any1 help.? pls

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you shouldn't develop applications as **Admin** user - its purpose is to *administer* Apex.

Therefore: as you already created a workspace and a schema, then - still connected as Admin

- create another user - **developer**
- *join* previously created workspace with newly created developer user

  - that developer will be using schema you created as its *default* schema

    - later, if you want, you can add another schemas to it
- log out
- log in as a developer, this time providing worspace/username/password combination that belongs to the developer